# Accepting a self-answer months later, containing information within the prior answer

Tags: discussion

The best answer can change over time (and should be re-assignable as such); and the asking person may be the best resource to eventually answer their own question (it is a problem dearer to them than to us).

That said, would it be considered an appropriate action to automatically flag for review a newly minted self-accepted answer in the event that the question was answered three or more months prior?

Flagging for review doesn't imply that the user did something wrong, it just implies that a moderator would need to inspect the situation to determine that the user either:

- Found some new solution, detail, or evidence that improved upon the answer and as such should be captured through the existing self-answer mechanism.

or

- Determined that accepting their own answer with excerpts from a previously existing answers could benefit them in some way. (I already know that it won't give the acceptance points).

While the latter scenario borders anti-social behavior, a human needs to weigh in on whether anything truly odd occurred; hence the idea of auto-flagging instead of taking some (yet undetermined) action.

Comment: It depends... if it was 99.9% copied directly from another answer then it's a bit low. If it's a mash-up of a couple of answers with a bit of your own work thrown in that answers the question better than any of the previous answers did, or even could be considered canonical then why not?

Comment: It's basically one sentence taken out of the previously accepted question (which rambled a bit as the poster kept editing and clarifying their question).  This scenario is arguably low, but it could also be argued as "clarification".  It requires a judgement call, hence a human with guidelines.  Flagging seems to have semi-negative connotations, but is auto "request review" a good idea at all?